# SQLITE3 / Python - Database disk image malformed but integrity_check ok

Tags: python, sqlite, select, multiprocessing, malformed

My actual problem is that `python` `sqlite3` module throws `database disk image malformed`.

Now there must be a million possible reasons for that. However, I can provide a number of clues:

- I am using `python` `multiprocessing` to spawn a number of workers that all **read** (not write) from this DB
- The problem definitely has to do with multiple processes accessing the DB, which fails on the remote setup but not on the local one. If I use only one worker on the remote setup, it works
- The same 6GB database works perfectly well on my local machine. I copied it with `git` and later again with `scp` to remote. There the same script with the copy of the original DB gives the error
- Now if I do `PRAGMA integrity_check` on the remote, it returns `ok` after a while - even after the problem occurred
- Here are the versions (OS are both `Ubuntu`):

  1. local:  `sqlite3.version >>> 2.6.0`, `sqlite3.sqlite_version >>> 3.22.0`
  2. remote: `sqlite3.version >>> 2.6.0`, `sqlite3.sqlite_version >>> 3.28.0`

Do you have some ideas how to allow for save "parallel" `SELECT`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was for the following reason (and it had happened to me before):

Using `multiprocessing` with `sqlite3`, make sure to **create a separate connection for each worker**!

Apparently this causes problems with some setups and sometimes doesn't.